# Orthogonal procrustes with kernel constraint

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, least-squares, procrustes-problem

Given a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ with $n > m$ and an arbitrary vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, I am looking for an analytical solution for the orthogonal matrix $R \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ with $R^T R = I_m$ that minimizes
$$
\lVert R - M \rVert_{F}^2 
$$
subject to the hard constraint
$$
R^T v = 0.
$$
In other words, I'm looking for the closest orthogonal matrix $R$ to $M$ whose columns are perpendicular to $v$.

It seems one way to get an orthogonal $R$ from $M$ satisfying this constraint would be to perform Gram-Schmidt with $v$ as the first basis vector and the columns of $M$ as the others. However, this is perhaps not the minimal solution satisfying the constriant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\k{\otimes} \def\h{\odot}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Use the vector $v$ and an unconstrained matrix $A\in\R{n\times m}\,$ to construct $\,B$
$$\eqalign{
B &= \LR{I-\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}}A \qiq v^TB = 0
\qquad \qquad \quad
}$$
Then use $B$ to construct $\,R$
$$\eqalign{
R &= B\LR{B^TB}^{-1/2} \quad\qiq v^TR=0,\quad R^TR = I
}$$
Minimizing the objective function is then an **unconstrained** problem to find $A$.